# Translate content in a Play 2.2 application

Tags: database-design, internationalization, playframework-2.0

I am developing a Play app that will handle product categories, products...
My application must handle several languages : fr, en, es, de.

I have no problem with the translation of "interface" elements like page titles etc... This is easily done via conf/messages files.

But I did not found any resource talking about the translation of the content. For example, the name of a category is different in the several languages.

**Expermimental solution :**

I've come up with a first solution but i'm scared it will lead to poor performances when the website grows. Let's say i have these entities :

```
Lang : id, code, name
Category : id, code
I18nCategory : category_id, lang_id, name, description
Product : id, code
I18nProduct : product_id, lang_id, name, description, short_description
```

As you see, I must have two entities instead of one for the entities that have fields to translate. If I have **Product 1**, I will have a line for each lang in the I18nProduct table.

Do you think it is a good pattern, or absolutely not a good idea ?
How do the big projects manage this (Amazon, eBay...) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know about Amazon, but solution I inherited from TYPO3 [typo3](/questions/tagged/typo3) is using single models with additionall fields like:

```
Category: 
   Integer    id
   String     code
   Lang       lang
   Category   i18n_parent
   String     name
   String     description
```

In such case to get record in default lang SQL would be:

```
SELECT * FROM category WHERE id = 123 AND i18_parent_id IS NULL
```

for not default language you need to fetch 2 records at once:

```
SELECT * FROM category WHERE id = 123 AND i18_parent_id IS NULL OR (lang_id = 2 AND i18_parent_id = 123)
```

And then join both rows into one object by using values from original langage if ie in translated record it's null

For building ie. lists of translated records, in first query select all required records in default language (without i18n_parent) collect their uids and select all records where `lang_id=2` and `i18n_parent_uid in (1,2,3,4)` and perform translation of each set as in single record

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it is a good one as well. But what bothers me is that you have to make concessions on not null and unique fields. For example, in my case, a product code must be unique, i have to change the constraint to make (code, lang_id) unique... But having only one class per object is more maintanable, i'll change for yours. Thanks !